# MEAN Stack: Very specific web requests to generic model methods, or generic web requests with very specific model methods?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, curl

I have inherited a code base with several explicit methods on each model, and I've started to notice that most, if not all of these methods could be reduced to four generic Create, Read, Update, and Delete (CRUD) methods, by simply passing the appropriate JSON into them from either routes or web requests, rather than explicitly defining things such as mongo queries within the model.

My question is: have I stumbled onto best practices, or does this simplification introduce some security hole or authentication problems I just don't see yet?

For example, all of these methods exist in models/user.js:

```
module.exports.getUserByID = function (id, callback) {
    const query = {'_id': id };
    User.findOne(query, callback);
};

module.exports.getUserByUsername = function (username, callback) {
    const query = {'username': username};
    User.findOne(query, callback);
};

module.exports.getUserByFullname = function (fullname, callback) {
        const query = {'name.fullname': fullname};
        User.findOne(query, callback);
    };
```

... and I want to combine them into a single method...

```
models/user.js:
    module.exports.getUser = function (query, callback) {
        User.findOne(query, callback);
    };
```

Would I then need three different POST routes (`/users/byId, /users/byName, and users/byFullName`), or possibly one POST route, `users/getUser`, that can be passed specific queries from cURL (`{'_id':"'$userID'"}, {'username':"'$userName'"},{'name.fullname':"'$userFullName'"}`)?

I hope to reduce every models/*.js to a schema and four methods, leaving it to either the routes or web requests to supply all the JSON needed to, for example, update a record. I'm just not sure which of the three options (several model methods(current implementation), several routes, or several web requests) is best practice.

What possible future issues am I not thinking of? Is simplifying the model methods actually the way it should have been written from the start?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **[`req.query`](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.query)** object for your generic queries.
For example, a GET request on the route `/users/getUser?_id=<some_user_id>` or  `/users/getUser?username=<some_user_name>` or `/users/getUser?fullname=<some_full_name>`  can be implemented as follows:

```
var getUser = require('models/user');
app.get('/users/getUser', (req, res, next) => {
    let query = req.query;
    if (req.query.fullname) {
        query['name.fullname'] = req.query.fullname;
        delete query.fullname;
    }

    getUser(query, (err, user) => {
        if (err) handleError(err);
        console.log(user);
    });
});
```